# ORA-00904: sysdate invalid identifier error

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00904, sysdate

I am trying to run below query in Oracle but getting this error. Any idea how to resolve?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.p_id "Id",
    (TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY') + least(SIGN(("sysdate" - to_date('01-Aug-' | | TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0)) "Year"

    FROM 
       t1,
       t7,
       t9
    WHERE 
       t9.ei_id(+)          = t7.e_id
    AND (t7.e_student        = t1.p_id)
    AND (t7.e_module         = t8.m_id)
    AND (NVL(t9.ei_q18m06, t7.e_end) > '31-Jul-' | | (TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY') + least(SIGN(("sysdate" - to_date('01-Aug-' | | TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0) + - 5))
```

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: For starters, don't put `SYSDATE` in quotes.

Comment: Thank you looks like its working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vijay states, you should write it so (I also fixed your `| |` who might cause other error: -> `||`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.p_id "Id",
(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') + least(SIGN((sysdate - to_date('01-Aug-' || TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0)) "Year"
FROM 
   t1,
   t7,
   t9
WHERE 
   t9.ei_id(+)          = t7.e_id
AND (t7.e_student        = t1.p_id)
AND (t7.e_module         = t8.m_id)
AND (NVL(t9.ei_q18m06, t7.e_end) > '31-Jul-' || (TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') + least(SIGN((sysdate - to_date('01-Aug-' || TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0) + - 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to give sysdate under inverted commas,just give sysdate.
currently it is taking as string so giving u invalid identifier error.